# How to correctly use CPointer and CStruct in NativeCall interface

Tags: posix, raku, nativecall

I am trying to get this example of [`NativeCall`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Getting_Started) running:

```
use NativeCall;

class p_timespec is repr('CPointer') {
    has uint32 $.tv_sec;
    has long $.tv_nanosecs;
}

sub clock_gettime(uint32 $clock-id, p_timespec $tspec --> uint32) is native(Str) { * };

my p_timespec $this-time;

my $result = clock_gettime( 0, $this-time);

say "$result, $this-time";
```

It simply segfaults, which is what happens when you use pointers and you should not. In this case, it's probably due to the declaration of `p_timespec`; I have actually declared it as a `CPointer`, although [the struct should be OK](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec). However, from the segmentation fault I can't fathom what's really wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: It might be (nearly) impossible to make more forgiving, simply because the C side doesn't do any validations. In the end, you'll have to use the usual C debugging tools (like gdb, valgrind) to your aid.

Comment: Shouldn't the repr be `CStruct` insetad of `CPointer`? Atributes on a `CPointer` make no sense and probably should be made to throw a compiler error...

Comment: Do you have the right type for `p_timespec.tv_sec` for your system? On my system it should be an `int64`, not `uint32`

Comment: @Kaiepi it seems to be a bit more forgiving in that sense. The problem is declaring a CPointer with structure, apparently.

Comment: @jjmerelo: are you working on a Perl 6 version of `Time::HiRes` by any chance?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen maybe I should; but I'm just trying to get some real use case examples for the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's two things wrong here.

1. The `CStruct` representation should be used
2. You need to make an instance of the structure for it to fill out with data, otherwise you're passing a null pointer

This seems to work:

```
use NativeCall;

class p_timespec is repr('CStruct') {
    has uint32 $.tv_sec;
    has long $.tv_nanosecs;
}

sub clock_gettime(uint32 $clock-id, p_timespec $tspec --> uint32) is native(Str) { * };

my p_timespec $this-time .= new;

my $result = clock_gettime( 0, $this-time);

say "$result, $this-time.tv_sec(), $this-time.tv_nanosecs()";
```

As for debugging, Rakudo's installation process also installs a `perl6-gdb-m` and a `perl6-valgrind-m`; the latter, while slow, will tend to provide some useful information on memory errors.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does virtually no one use the `repr<CStruct>` syntax?

Comment: In fact, clock_gettime uses a pointer as a second argument. Does this mean that you can use CStruct instead of CPointers? When do you actually need to use CPointers?

Comment: A `CStruct` instance already is passed as a pointer to the memory, so there's no need for an extra level of pointer. `CPointer` is useful when you have want to deal with a data structure simply as an opaque pointer, without caring what is inside of it. This works out well when, for example, having a C library that allocates/frees the structure and provides functions for operating on it, and you should never poke into it directly.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington "`CPointer` ... to deal with ... as an opaque pointer ... and you should never poke into it directly." Would you say [Christoph's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997598/how-to-correctly-use-cpointer-and-cstruct-in-nativecall-interface#comment87012281_49997598) is spot on, or at least that use of `has` and/or `HAS` with a `repr('CPointer')` warrants a warning?